# ERROR ITMS - 90725: SDK version issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, app-store-connect

I am suffering one issue while archiving and uploading build from xCode 8.3.2

Please check below image to identify issue:

[image: Issue image]

I googled a lot for this issue, but not able to get any solution.

I have tried multiple options to solve this as below:

Option 1 - I have archived build from xCode 8.3.2 and tried to upload from xCode 9.0 or later.

Option 2 - I tried to archive and export build from xCode 8.3.2 and tried to upload from application loader of xCode 9.0 or later.

Option 3 - I have change my minimum deployed version from 9.0 to 11.0 archive a new build and try to upload with step 1 and 2.

One version is already live and I need to update version with minor changes.

I read too many blogs, All are suggestion to update code with xCode 9.0.

As I have used to many library and framework, I not able to update my code from Swift 3.1 to Swift 3.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Archiving the build on Xcode 8 will always use iOS 10.x SDK but the AppStore now allows only apps archived with iOS 11.x SDK to be submitted.

This means you need to archive your build using Xcode 9 because only this version of Xcode has iOS 11 SDK support.

Once you archive the build, you will be able to upload it to the AppStore.
But this means you will need to bump your Swift version too.
You'll **have to** now.

Comment: You mean to say minimum deployment target should be 11.x. Right?

Comment: @Er.ShreyanshShah No, deployment target can be lower but the build has to be with the iOS 11 SDK. i.e The archived build should be generated by Xcode 9.

Comment: @Er.ShreyanshShah And afaik, once you open your project in Xcode 9, you'll **have to** update your project from Swift 3.1 to Swift 3.2 in order to create a build that AppStore will accept for submission.

Comment: Ok. Let me try with this. Respond you once done.

Comment: Is there any solution without change of swift version?

Comment: @ShahabuddinVansiwala I doubt. Apple's system is constrained by certain rules.

Comment: @staticVoidMan You are right. There is no any option to update swift version of the project.